# Close popup when clicking on another popup eventListener

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

I've used `eventListener` to close popups when I click off them but the popup still shows when I click on another popup. Is there a way to fix this without changing too much of my code?

I'm new to JS so I'm keeping things as simple as possible. Ideally I want to keep the `eventListener` function because it works really well to close the popups without having to manually close each one, apart from this one thing.

```js
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  
function myFunction() {
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup') && popup.classList.contains('show')) myFunction();
});

var popup2 = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  
function myFunction2() {
  popup2.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup') && popup2.classList.contains('show')) myFunction2();
});
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<h2>Popup2</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction2()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">A Simple Popup again!</span>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, but the way you've written it is making it difficult. We can better solve this using a `forEach` loop and generic function:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vpr4Lh62/

```js
// constants
const SHOW_CLASS = 'show'

// clears any active popups by removing the show class from all popup texts
// note: could be further optimized by storing the "active" popup in a variable whenver it's clicked, and only unsetting that one in this function
const clearPopups = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.popuptext').forEach(text => text.classList.remove(SHOW_CLASS))
}

// keep behavior to clear popups when clicking outside of popup
window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    if(!target.classList.contains('popup')) {
    clearPopups()
  }
})

// instead of creating click handlers for each popup, we can create them all at once using a forEach loop

// first grab all the popups on the page
const popups = document.querySelectorAll('.popup')

// set a click handler on each popup
popups.forEach(popup => {
  // we can also set the event listener on the popup, instead on the entire window
  popup.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    // grab the first child, which will be the span
    const span = popup.children[0]
    // clear all the popups first
    clearPopups()
    // then set this one to be shown
    span.classList.add(SHOW_CLASS)
  })
})
```

This also means we can simplify our HTML:

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
<h2>Popup</h2>

<!-- You should never use onclick, this is old. Click handlers should be set using javascript -->
<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <!-- We also don't need the ID here anymore -->
  <span class="popuptext">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<h2>Popup2</h2>

<div class="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext">A Simple Popup again!</span>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it as simple and least amount of change (but by far not an ideal solution) is this:

For the window click handlers you need to be able to differentiate between the two popups, currently you are using a `.popup` class as a check if it's not the closest thing in both cases, so when you click on a second popup, the `myFunction()` is not executed.

What I added here is new class names to the popups, 'one' and 'two' respectively.

```
<body style="text-align:center">
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup one" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<h2>Popup2</h2>

<div class="popup two" onclick="myFunction2()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">A Simple Popup again!</span>
</div>


</body>
```

Then in your javascript code you can target them by modifying the selectors ever so slightly:

```
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  
function myFunction() {
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup.one') && popup.classList.contains('show')) myFunction();
});

var popup2 = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  
function myFunction2() {
  popup2.classList.toggle("show");
}

window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.closest('.popup.two') && popup2.classList.contains('show')) myFunction2();
});
```

Again, this is by no means a good coding standard nor the best solution but effectively the simplest one with least alteration to the code.
I hope this helps in terms of making sense why the issue occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to your problem.

[Mohd Belal Toggle popus JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bredbizz/o8aLs90x/3/)

Points covered in this jsfiddle

```
1. 2 Popus have been taken for now
2. Popus will toggle other popup opened
3. Clicking on area other than popup will close the popup
```

Hope you got your solution @Joe